# how to impelment twitter follow button on C# desktop application

Tags: c#, winforms, twitter, twitter-follow

I have window form is C# and I want to impelment a twitter button in the winform, when I click on the follow button then it will increas the followers in my twitter account.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: No I am starting R&D but I can't able to find anything, so please help me...

Answer (score 2):

I saw a post about this. But it is Turkish, so I want to share code here:

```
HttpWebRequest messageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://twitter.com/friendships/create/" + userIdToFollow + ".xml?follow=true");
messageRequest.Method = "POST";
messageRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
messageRequest.ContentLength = 0;
messageRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
WebResponse response = messageRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
responseStr = sReader.ReadToEnd();
```

You can check [the whole page](http://www.csharptr.com/c-ile-twitter-islemleri).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a follow link

https://twitter.com/intent/follow?original_referer=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F1.1&region=follow_link&screen_name=twitterapi&tw_p=followbutton&variant=2.0

You will have to use a web browser control or launch a browser to do a get or post to the URL.  The funky characters are just escaped. You should be able to hack this link to suit.

More info-

https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#follow